# Different results from several "passes" of Random Forest on same dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning, self-study, cross-validation, random-forest

I've been playing around with the `German Credit` dataset available in Kuhn & Johnson's `caret` package for `R`.

First, I build a very simple model (I'm not using CV to simplify the code; this is taken from their examples in the `AppliedPredictiveModeling` package):

```
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
data(GermanCredit)

GermanCredit <- GermanCredit[, -nearZeroVar(GermanCredit)]
GermanCredit$CheckingAccountStatus.lt.0 <- NULL
GermanCredit$SavingsAccountBonds.lt.100 <- NULL
GermanCredit$EmploymentDuration.lt.1 <- NULL
GermanCredit$EmploymentDuration.Unemployed <- NULL
GermanCredit$Personal.Male.Married.Widowed <- NULL
GermanCredit$Property.Unknown <- NULL
GermanCredit$Housing.ForFree <- NULL

set.seed(100)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(GermanCredit$Class, p = .8)[[1]]
GermanCreditTrain <- GermanCredit[ inTrain, ]
GermanCreditTest  <- GermanCredit[-inTrain, ]

set.seed(1056)
credit.rf <- randomForest(Class~., data = GermanCreditTrain, ntree = 500)
```

Now, if I predict the outcome `Class` on the test set, and do this several times:

```
credit.pred1 <- predict(credit.rf, GermanCreditTest)
credit.pred2 <- predict(credit.rf, GermanCreditTest)
credit.pred3 <- predict(credit.rf, GermanCreditTest)
```

and compare the predictions:

```
credit.pred1 == credit.pred2
credit.pred2 == credit.pred3
credit.pred1 == credit.pred3
```

I see that the same model, on the same dataset, makes slightly different decisions.

Why is this? I understand this is normal when building a model using cross-validation (or not, as we unfortunately see all too often), but I thought that when a model was built, it would be making the exact same decisions on a certain test set every time you run it?

**EDIT:** I tried again as asked, and still have the same problem. Here's the output from `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252       LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] randomForest_4.6-10 pmml_1.2.30         XML_3.98-1.1        caret_6.0-35        ggplot2_1.0.0       lattice_0.20-29    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] BradleyTerry2_1.0-5 brglm_0.5-9         car_2.0-21          codetools_0.2-8       colorspace_1.2-4    digest_0.6.4       
 [7] foreach_1.4.2       grid_3.1.1          gtable_0.1.2        gtools_3.4.1        iterators_1.0.7     lme4_1.1-7         
[13] MASS_7.3-33         Matrix_1.1-4        minqa_1.2.4         munsell_0.4.2       nlme_3.1-117        nloptr_1.0.4       
[19] nnet_7.3-8          plyr_1.8.1          proto_0.3-10        Rcpp_0.11.3         reshape2_1.4        scales_0.2.4       
[25] splines_3.1.1       stringr_0.6.2       tools_3.1.1
```

**EDIT 2:** This is unbelievable. When I copy the code I posted on CrossValidated for the website, the model produces the same results. But when I copy the code from my code editor (Sublime Text 2.0.2 with the Enhanced-R plugin) into RStudio, I run into the same problem I've described! Here's the address to the Gist I created, it reproduces the problem: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/32b3c8194362d2e10527

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As advised by @John Richardson when I crossposred the question to SO, I tried using the `train` function from the `caret` package for building the model:

```
credit.rf <- randomForest(Class~., data = GermanCreditTrain, ntree = 500)
```

That solves the problem. But I still have absolutely no idea what's causing it!

Answer (score 2):

Random forests use [bootstrap sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) to build many different decision trees on the same dataset.  While each individual decision would fit the same model to the exact same data, you get a different aggregate model each run because you take different bootstrap samples each run.

---

**Edit:** I misunderstood your question.  First of all, when I run your code, I DO get the exact same results for `credit.pred1`, `credit.pred2`, `credit.pred3`.  Please start a new R session, re-run your code, and check your results. Furthermore, use this code to check equality:

```
all.equal(credit.pred1, credit.pred2)
all.equal(credit.pred2, credit.pred3)
all.equal(credit.pred1, credit.pred3)
```

if you STILL get different results, run `sessionInfo()` and post the results here.

Answer (score 2):

I also incurred the same problem `randomForest` function giving different values for different passes. As Zach mentioned: random forest algorithm randomly creates multiple subsets of the data, the end results might vary slightly for different passes. To overcome this, I simple ran `set.seed(500)` every time before a new pass, so as to reset the seed to `500` and it is giving me exact mirror results. I hope it helped.